# NuxtPress Tag, Categories, Taxonomies, etc

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, nuxt.js, blogs

I've read through the NuxtPress Documentation (https://nuxt.press/en/guide/#setup) and maybe I just didn't get it but is there a way to add tags, categories, and/or custom taxonomy to each `.md` file and be able to have a page show a list of tags/categories/custom taxonomy? Is there also a way to have urls generated for the taxonomies? For example, `somewebsite.com/:tags` or `somewebsite.com/:tag/:md_identifier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuxtPress is or will be unsupported in favor of the module `@nuxt/context`.

The `@nuxt/content` module enables tags, categories, and custom taxonomies. I have tried it on a Nuxt project.

Here's the GitHub answer: https://github.com/nuxt/press/issues/101

Here's the official documentation of `@nuxt/context` module: https://content.nuxtjs.org/